# How do I completely uninstall Xcode command line tools?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode-command-line-tools

How do I uninstall the *entire* command line tools package from Xcode 8? Deleting /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools is insufficient, because the package installs header files to /usr/include and /System/Library/Frameworks. Unfortunately, /System and /usr are protected by SIP, so once the files are installed, they cannot be deleted.

Is there a "proper" way to uninstall these headers. Note that the closest solution is https://gist.github.com/githubutilities/b5318d08a4b970d104f1, but that would require disabling SIP, which seems ridiculous.